# Map giving wrong values

Tags: c++, stl

In a puzzle in [CodinGame](https://www.codingame.com) called [MIME Type](https://www.codingame.com/training/easy/mime-type), we're asked to make a program that:

- Acquires a database of extensions and their corresponding MIME types.
- Reads several names of files.
- Prints the corresponding MIME type for each file. If the file's extension doesn't exist in the database, it should print UNKNOWN instead.
- Detects extensions in a case-insensitive way. For example, if we know the MIME type image/png, no matter how the extension appears in the file name ("pic.png" or "pic.PNG" or "pic.PnG"), the program should be able to tell that its MIME type is image/png

I was able to solve this puzzle. My first attempt, that I present here, is more complicated. I'm posting it in this question, however, because I had a weird bug and I couldn't figure out what was the reason behind it.

Consider the following file ("MIME.dat") that contains extensions and their corresponding MIME types:

```
html
text/html
png
image/png
gif
image/gif
```

Consider as well the following file ("names.dat) that contains the name of the files:

```
animated.gIf
portrait.png
index.html
```

The expected output is (following the order by which the names appear in the file):

```
image/gif
image/png
text/html
```

Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

struct cmp_ins {
    bool operator()(const string& s1, const string& s2) const
    {
        if(s1.length()!=s2.length())
            return false;
        else
        {
            bool b=true;
            string::const_iterator i,j;
            for(i=s1.begin(), j=s2.begin(); b && i!=s1.end();++i,++j)
            {
                if((isalpha(*i) && isalpha(*j)) && (toupper(*i)!=toupper(*j)))
                    b=false;
                else if((isalpha(*i) && !isalpha(*j)) || (!isalpha(*i) && isalpha(*j)))
                    b=false;
                else if((!isalpha(*i) && !isalpha(*j)) && *i!=*j)
                    b=false;
            }
            return b;
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    try
    {
        map<string,string,cmp_ins> db;
        string name,MT;
        string::iterator j;
        ifstream fdb("MIME.dat"), fn("names.dat");
        if(!fdb.is_open())
            throw runtime_error("Couldn't open MIME.dat");
        if(!fn.is_open())
            throw runtime_error("Couldn't open names.dat");
        struct cmp_ins obj;//Will be used to verify if cmp_ins works correctly
        while(fdb >> name >> MT)
        {
            db[name]=MT;
            cout << "(" << name << "," << MT << ")" << endl;
        }
        cout << endl;
        fdb.close();
        while(fn >> name)
        {
            cout << "name:" << name << endl;
            for(j=name.end();*j!='.' && j!=name.begin();--j);
            if(*j!='.')
                cout << "UNKNOWN" << endl;
            else
            {
                string ac=name.substr(j-name.begin()+1,name.end()-j);
                cout << ac << "=gif? " << obj(ac,string("gif")) << endl;
                map<string,string,cmp_ins>::iterator t=db.find(ac);
                cout << "MIME: ";
                if(t==db.end())
                    cout << "UNKNOWN" << endl;
                else
                    cout << t->second << endl;
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
        fn.close();
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
    catch(exception& e)
    {
        cerr << e.what() << endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
}
```

Here's the output:

```
(html,text/html)
(png,image/png)
(gif,image/gif)

name:animated.gIf
gIf=gif? 1
MIME: image/gif

name:portrait.png
png=gif? 0
MIME: image/gif

name:index.html
html=gif? 0
MIME: UNKNOWN
```

As you can see, the program considers "portrait.png" as an image/gif file, while png!= gif, and the function cmp_ins was able to tell the difference (it return 0). Also, the program wasn't able to recognize the type of "index.html".

Could you please tell me what's wrong?

Comment: Have you run through the code with your debugger to see where it falls apart?

Comment: @NathanOliver Yes I did, using GDB. I didn't know how to use it to access to the function inside the struct (I know how to access to methods of classes, but couldn't do it for this struct). However, it doesn't seem to be the real cause as it's returning the correct values.

Comment: The comparison function for a map needs to specify a [strict weak ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_ordering#Strict_weak_orderings) relation. Anything else is undefined. It's not clear at all what yours is doing.

Comment: @molbdnilo Yes you're right! My bad. Thank you very much!

Comment: By the way, if you want to compare two strings for case-insensitive equality, you can simply uppercase (or lowercase) both and use `==`, or pass their `.c_str()`s to `stricmp`.

Comment: To paraphrase @molbdnilo, map's comparator must represent "less" relationship, while your comparator represents "equals" relationship.

Comment: @molbdnilo Yes you're right. That's in fact the trick that used to solve this program. In fact, I didn't even introduce a comparator for map. I simply, as you said, uppercased all the extensions.

Comment: @Arkadiy Thank you for your effort to clarify :) Don't worry about that, I'm a math major ;)

Comment: @Scientifica  "Oh! I am sorry to hear it - most concerned. Is there no remedy?"    ;-)

Comment: @Arkadiy hhhh xD loool whyyyy lol? Otherwise, unless I misunderstood something and I apologize if that's the case, I sincerely appreciated your comment; the reason why I said that is to spare any user writing a comment to further explain that concept, as you did. Nothing else.

Comment: :) It's from "HMS Surprise". Just search for  "most concerned. Is there no remedy" on Google, quotes and all. I just could not help myself.

Comment: Ah ok cool then (y) :D That was my misunderstanding; I apologize. hhhhh well there is a remedy: just do what you love and love what you do :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your comparator to be used with `std::map` it must satisfy [Compare](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Compare) concept:

> The return value of the function call operation applied to an object of type Compare, when contextually converted to bool, yields true if the first argument of the call appears before the second in the strict weak ordering relation induced by this Compare type, and false otherwise.

Your comparator seems to return true if objects equal, which is not what required by this concept. You need to rewrite it to satisfy "strict weak ordering relation"